# Getting the cell value of two string variables

Tags: vba, excel

I have a 2D chart in Excel. I need to get the value of a cell using two string variables. The chart looks like this:

```
Document     person1    person2
Text1        5          8
Text2        2          1
Text3        9          6
```

After looking online I am finding this difficult because:

1. the values are strings, not integers;
2. the strings will change depending on which person and document combination comes up.

This should be the only code that is relevant:

```
Dim document as string
Dim person as string

Dim oExcel as excel.application
Dim oWB as workbook
Set oExcel = New Excel.application
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.open.      ("C:")
oExcel.Visible = True

oWB.Sheets ("sheet1").Cells(documemt, person)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that document and person are string variables that hold string representations of integers (e.g. document = "1", person = "2") then something like

```
oWB.Sheets ("sheet1").Cells(val(document), val(person))
```

will work. If the contents of the string variables are more complicated then you would need to do some parsing of those strings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming by "2d Chart" you mean a table in a Worksheet, and that person would be the full text "person1", or "person2", etc. and likewise for document, then perhaps this function will do the trick.

```
Function FindDocPerson(person As String, document As String) As Variant
    Const MatchExact As Integer = 0
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim table As Excel.Range
    Set table = ws.UsedRange

    Dim docRange As Excel.Range
    Set docRange = table.Columns(1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(table.Columns(1).Rows.Count - 1)

    Dim personRange As Excel.Range
    Set personRange = table.Rows(1).Offset(0, 1).Resize(1, table.Columns.Count - 1)

    Dim personIndex As Long
    Dim docIndex As Long

    On Error GoTo errHandler

    personIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(person, personRange, MatchExact) + 1
    docIndex = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(document, docRange, MatchExact) + 1
    FindDocPerson = table.Cells(docIndex, personIndex).Value2
    Exit Function

errHandler:
    FindDocPerson = VBA.CVErr(Excel.xlErrNA)
End Function
```

calling syntax:

```
Dim result As Variant
result = FindDocPerson("person2", "text1")

If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsError(result) Then
    ' handle it
Else
    ' found it
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code,

```
oWB.Sheets ("sheet1").Cells(documemt, person)
```

documemt should be document

All that aside though it is unclear what you want to do, can you give a little more description please?

All we know is you need to get the value of a cell using two string variables and that it could be a string or a number. The code you posted doesn't give much more of a hint to your goal.

To convert between strings and numbers you can use CLng to convert to a long number or CStr to convert to a string. eg CLng("3") = 3 and CStr(3) = "3"

In your code this:

```
Set oWB = oExcel.Workbooks.open.      ("C:")
```

Doesn't work because you are trying to open a workbook without specifying a name, I also note the ("C:") is spaced far to the right of the command call which leads me to believe this is has been typed freestyle ie not in the VBE. This makes it even harder to decode into your requirements.

Lastly, this code:

```
Set oExcel = New Excel.application
```

Why are you starting another session of Excel from Excel VBA code? Is this code somewhere other than Excel ie Outlook / Access / PowerPoint / Word / Business Objects etc etc.